# Is there way to get required field array in draft-07 json schema through java code

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, pojo

I want to generate json schema of draft-04 or draft-07 with required array for mandatory fields?

I am new to JSON schema, so able to generate draft-07 schema with victools:

Sharing code for same:

```
SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder configBuilder = new SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder(SchemaVersion.DRAFT_7, OptionPreset.PLAIN_JSON);
SchemaGeneratorConfig config = configBuilder.build();
SchemaGenerator generator = new SchemaGenerator(config);
JsonNode jsonSchema = generator.generateSchema("MyClassName".class);

System.out.println(jsonSchema.toString());
```

The o/P i got is:

Json schema for draft-07 like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "ActiveOrHistoricCurrencyAndAmount": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "ccy": { "type": "string" },
        "value": { "type": "number" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**what i wanted is:**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "ActiveOrHistoricCurrencyAndAmount": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "ccy": { "type":"string" },
        "value": { "type":"number" }
      },
      "required": ["ccy", "value"]
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted required array for mandatory fields also , so how to generate this using java?

Comment: Did you mark your ccy property as required in the input (which you didn't provide)?

Comment: yes ..it is marked as required =true in pojo class

Comment: Then this is an issue with whatever tool you are using to generate the schema.

Answer (score 1):

victools generator **4.17.0** currently does not support the `required` attribute of the Jackson annotation `@JsonProperty(required=true)` out of the box . It is scheduled for the next version, and will probably be enabled with the option `JacksonOption.RESPECT_JSONPROPERTY_ORDER` set to `true`.
see [victools changelog](https://github.com/victools/jsonschema-generator/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Until then, you could customize the SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder to *support this attribute* like this :

```
SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder configBuilder = new SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder(SchemaVersion.DRAFT_7, OptionPreset.PLAIN_JSON);

configBuilder.forFields()
       .withRequiredCheck(field -> {
            JsonProperty jsonProperty = field.getAnnotationConsideringFieldAndGetter(JsonProperty.class) ;
            if ( jsonProperty == null )
                 return false;  // No @JsonProperty ? => field not required.
            else
                 return jsonProperty.required(); // let's respect what the 'required' says
       });

SchemaGeneratorConfig config = configBuilder.build();
SchemaGenerator generator = new SchemaGenerator(config);
JsonNode jsonSchema = generator.generateSchema("MyClassName".class);
```

(disclaimer: I recently submitted the PR for this feature)